# Unknown NullPointerException when trying to run Apache MyFaces 2.0.2 application

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, myfaces, trinidad

I am trying to run a sample JSF 2.0 application which is built on `Apache MyFaces 2.0.2` and `Apache Trinindad 2.0.1`. I am running on `weblogic 11g`. I am encountering an `NullPointerException` in trinidad internal classes which i am unable to debug. Here is the exception

```
javax.faces.FacesException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.wrap(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:241)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:156)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at com.others.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:768)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl._getInternalView(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:104)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:128)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:150)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171)
    ... 20 more
```

This error is encountered after `RESTOREVIEW PHASE` of the lifecycle.
Here is my `web.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>/*appname*/</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
 <context-param>
  <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name> 
  <param-value>true</param-value> 
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
     <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
     <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/adf/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
    <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/others/Error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
    <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.NullPointerException</exception-type>
    <location>/others/Error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>
```

And here is my `faces-config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>messages</base-name>
            <var>msgs</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    <default-render-kit-id>
        org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.core
    </default-render-kit-id>  
  </application>

    <lifecycle>
        <phase-listener>com.others.LifeCycleListener</phase-listener>
    </lifecycle>

</faces-config>
```

And Here is the `Home.xhtml` which i am trying to access

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:tr="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad"
    xmlns:trh="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html">

<h:body>
<ui:composition template="../Templates/homelayout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="pagetitle">Home</ui:define>


    <ui:define name="bodycontent">
        <h:outputText value="This is an output text"/>
        <h:outputText value="This is an output text"/>
        <h:outputText value="This is an output text"/>
        <h:outputText value="This is an output text"/>
        <h:outputText value="This is an output text"/>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>

</h:body>
```

And Here is my folder structure snapshot

[image]

Can somebody please explain me the reason for the Nullpointer Exception? and also How to solve it?

Thanks in Advance.

Update: I removed the old `MyFaces 2.0.2` jars and added `MyFaces 2.0.14` jars. I also added an error page in the `web.xml` to get the complete error info. This is the exception message it throws now.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:768)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl._getInternalView(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:104)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerImpl.java:158)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.getViewDeclarationLanguage(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:128)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:151)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at com.others.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
```

Comment: MyFaces 2.0.2 is a very old version. Please try a newer version.

Comment: You could try setting up your project using Trinidad's Maven archetype http://myfaces.apache.org/build-tools/archetypes/myfaces-archetype-trinidad20/index.html

Comment: @lu4242 - I added the new version of MyFaces jars and also added an error page to get the actual error info. updated the question accordingly.please help.

Comment: Stracktrace suggests that `viewId` is `null`.

Comment: Your Trinidad filter is been mapped on a non-existent servlet name. You mapped it on `<servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>`, but your actual JSF servlet has the name `<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>`. Perhaps this is the root cause? (I can't confirm this from theory nor experience as I've never used Trinidad and the exception is very nasty). Fix the filter mapping accordingly and retry.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo error BalusC. I corrected it, but still the exception persists.

Comment: Everybody thanks for answering. Please see my answer. Can anybody try to explain the reason?

Comment: I'd bet a bug in MyFaces. A wrong URL should rather have resulted in 404 or maybe `FileNotFoundException`. Try a newer version, yours is almost 3 years old already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Solved it.

Thanks **BalusC** for pointing out the type error in `web.xml`.

**Solution:**

I was trying to access my application in the following way after changing the `faces servlet` mapping to `.xhtml`.

```
http://hostname/contextname/faces/others/Home.xhtml
```

Now i just removed `faces` from the url and started accessing my application like this

```
http://hostname/contextname/others/Home.xhtml
```

And to my surprise it did not give any exception and shows my Home page.